# how to fix 'str' object is not callable error in Python

Tags: python, string, callable-statement

I am trying to draw financial information for stocks through an API.

I am not able to provide input information into the code in order to assess different stocks.

When I introduce the input code I get the message:

```
TypeError: 'str' object is not callable.
```

This is the code that I am elaborating:

```
import requests

main_api = 'https://financialmodelingprep.com/api/v3/company/profile'
my_request = input('Which stock you look for? ') 
url = main_api + '/' + my_request
print(url)


request = requests.get(url,
  headers={
    "X-RapidAPI-Host": "investors-exchange-iex-trading.p.rapidapi.com",
    "X-RapidAPI-Key": 
"ab295550bemsh717b12e1a0e93e8p180b21jsn9e636c0d25ef"
  }
)
request_json = request.json()
print(request_json)
price = request_json['profile'][0]['price']
print("Today value:", price)
```

Thanks for any assistance or advice.

Comment: ... this doesn't look like php. PHP uses `$variables` and has semicolons (`;`). Unless there's something I didn't know about. Any idea what code is giving the `TypeError`? I'm not sure I see it in your question.

Comment: The error comes from the following code line.........my_request = input('Which stock you look for? ')

Comment: Is this Python?.